# prevent activity restarting when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android, xamarin, android-orientation

I am new to android development .I have separate screens for  portrait and landscape mode.When i change my orientation corresponding screen gets loaded and activity restarts . Now i do not want my activity to restart when i change the orientation but should load its corresponding screen(axml).

I have tried

> [Activity (Label =
>   "MyActivity",ConfigurationChanges=Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation)]

the above line stops activity getting restarted but it loads the same screen(axml).
Please suggest .
thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Write this code in your activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.landscapeView);

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.portraitView);
    }
}
```

And also add this line in your Manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

So this will handle both things, it will not restart your activity and will load the layout as per your orientation changes.

Comment: 11-07 13:44:47.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2586): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity

Shows this error when i include this

Comment: Where to add these code in mainActivity OR each Fragment in the activity and R.layout.landscapeView and R.layout.portraitView are two different layout

Answer (score 5):

Since you have specified to the OS that you want to handle orientation change yourself, now you have to handle any changes to the layout yourself, like this:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); 

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.portrait);
        //do other initialization
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.landscape);
        //do other initialization
    }
}
```

Comment: OnCreate() method is getting called for orientation changes.

Comment: @surjay You need to add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize` in your <activity tag in the Manifest file.