# Activity restart on rotation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, screen-rotation, adview

I have an activity. That activity contains a `Fragment` within a `ViewPager`. The fragment needs to copy files (with a `ProgressDialog`), but when I rotate the screen when it is busy, the activity restarts and everything just stops.

I tried adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to the AndroidManifest but that wont be a solution either because then my `AdView` and `Toolbar` won't reload on a rotation change:

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

(Notice the difference with the Toolbar and AdView height?)

How can I keep the Activity/Fragment alive, with a working `Toolbar` and `AdView`?

Thanks

Comment: you may need 2 layouts -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945130/prevent-activity-restarting-when-orientation-changes

Comment: make the app either portrait/landscape; do the app need to allow both orientation; if not u can use this in manifest under the activity tag android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: @DJphy The app needs to be able to rotate for a good user experience.

Comment: @Tasos the layout isn't the problem, the `Toolbar` and the `Adview` need to be "recreated".

Comment: all i can do is to give the question a vote; thats what i have done now; good question; but android can't help ur use case i guess :)

Comment: so use the orientation change function and restart the application -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564614/how-to-restart-an-android-application-programmatically

Comment: @Tasos Wouldn't that restart the whole activity? That's what I do not want because then a running `Thread` will be stopped.

Comment: yes it would, most probably you need to refresh the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> needs to copy files

what very little people usually realize about Android is that `Activity` and `Fragment` is not the place to execute long running operations, such as download stuff from internet or copying files.

Both `Activity` and `Fragment` are UI elements which can be destroyed, re-created, without much of a warning.

The correct way of dealing with such an issue is to have a `Service` to execute the long running operation, the `Activity` or `Fragment` should start the service and then immediately "bind" to it, executing the usual `unbind` and `bind` again upon rotation.

You can read here about service and bounds services: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

After the activity (or fragment) is bound to the `Service` then it can register it self as a listener and the service reports back to it the status/progress of the operation.

On top of it, if the activity disconnects from the service, the service can use the command `startForeground` to put a notification on the device status bar and keep notifying the user on the operation progress without the need of an `activity`

I know that way takes a lot more code and is more complex to do. But that is the **correct** way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this and accept if it worked.

Comment: One small question. Is it better to bind it with the `Fragment` or `Activity`?

Comment: It makes no difference. Bind from the one that controls the progress bar.

Comment: Look at other options, such as loaders before you go to these lengths

Comment: @brandall That might be a good solution, but I think I'll go with a `Service`. Then I can also do the stuff in the background so the user does not have to wait for it to finish.

Comment: @brandall Loaders is for loading data in a background thread to be delivered back to the UI. On this case he needs the process to be completed regardless of the presence of the UI

Comment: @Budius I got it working, but when you rotate the screen there is a small moment it is still binding to the service. Is there a way to fix that, or should I just leave that?

Comment: @Budius And does it matter if the service is still running in the background or should I kill the service?

Comment: @Budius there is no mention of that in the question, just a problem with screen rotation? If the OP needs this process to complete, rather than cancel if the app is closed, then your suggestion is correct one.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab that's normal, there's a few milliseconds until it gets bind. Normally is fast enough that the user don't see the difference. And kill the service when it is not needed anymore

Comment: @SuperThomasLab to kill the service use the `stopSelf()` command from the service itself.

Comment: @Budius Thanks for your help. I also put a boolean in savedinstancestate so you won't notice that the dialog is gone for a spit second.