# Intent camera from landscape orientation result error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera-intent

my app take a photo using intent. if i take with portrait orientation, i get the image. but when i rotate my device and take with landscape orientation, i got error. even the error message pointing to (maybe) the wrong line.

open camera:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(mainActivity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

on activity result:

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
ivImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

giving result as explained. then i try again with other code.
open camera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

on activity result:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;
imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);
ivImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

still have same result.
after looking some solution, they said about save instance. then i put this (i use fragment)

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

still not working and one of the error message pointing to

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) function

anyone know why? or maybe another alternate code using camera.

update, error message:

> Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method mypackagename.fragment.HomeFragment.access$super

and warning message

> unable to resolve virtual method 949: Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;.getAllocationByteCount

Comment: Add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` inside <activity ... "here" >

Comment: If you want your app to rotate then [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945130/prevent-activity-restarting-when-orientation-changes)

Comment: can you post the stacktrace??

Comment: @GeetChoubey i did with that manifest, but still not working. i tried from you link and still get error. i use fragment but put that method in actvity. and i'm not rotating the  app but taking picture in landscape, all my page is portrait.

Comment: @himanshu1496 what you  mean by stacktrace? btw i put error message and warning message, not sure if related with my problem

Comment: i meant your error logs, whatever error messages you are getting please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```